# html dom adding javascript functions

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the difference between these two:

```
document.form1.colorButton.onclick = setBGColor;`
```

and

```
<input name="colorButton" type="button"
       value="Change background color"
       onclick="setBGColor();"/>`
```

When adding it to the attribute there are () but when using the DOM no (). Why is this?

Any referencea to official documentation would help.

Comment: The first one is a function, the second is a string. The string is *evaluated* using `eval()`

Comment: @blgt: It doesn't use eval. The string becomes the body of a new function object.

Comment: try to type setBGColor in console, you will see it contains setBGColor().

Comment: @squint Fair point, but unless you're concerned with debugging or trying to leverage some usage of `this` it's equivalent. Just easier to think about in terms of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.onclick` version, you are directly assigning a reference to a JS function reference to the `.onclick` property.  It would be an error to supply the parentheses because that would result in the function being called immediately and its result being assigned to the event handler.

In the "inline" DOM0 method, the resulting code is more like:

```
document.form1.colorButton.onclick = function onclick(event) {
    setBGColor();
}
```

and in fact this is exactly what you'd see in a Chrome console if you used the inline method and then looked at the value of `document.form1.colorButton.onclick`.

To explain further, the body of the `onclick` attribute is wrapped up inside a new function and then the reference to *that* is assigned to the property.  You *must* supply the parentheses otherwise the `setBGColor()` function would not be invoked.